# Find increasing/decreasing values of $f(x)= \frac{1}{2}(3x-1)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$f(x)=  \frac{1}{2}(3x-1)\ \ \ \  x \le 3$$

I'm told I need to find where the derivative is increasing/decreasing. The problem is the $f'(x) =\frac{3}{2}$ so I'm not sure how to set this to zero to find the critical points.

Comment: It's never zero, so there are no critical points.

Comment: This is related to finding the absolute max/min

Comment: It's a line. It doesn't have critical points.

Comment: $f'>0$ then $f$ is always increasing, and $f''=0$ so $f'$ is constant.(to see it you do not even need to use derivative, it is like killing mosquito with atomic bomb)

Answer (score 1):

Since $f'$ is a constant it never changes,and since $f'>0$ it means $f$ is always increasing.You can also easily check that if $x>x_0$ then simplifying $\frac{1}{2}(3x-1)>\frac{1}{2}(3x_0-1)$ this gets $x>x_0$ so this implies it's increasing.